# File Transfer RMI

Tags: java, rmi, file-transfer

I am just following a tutorial on how to send files using RMI.

Tutorial: [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/rmi-corba-136641.html)

I encounter an error when i try to run my server. The only change i have made different from the tutorial is i have changed my port to 1097 instead of the default 1099.

How can i resolve this error?

This is the error i receive:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\FT_RMI>java -Djava.security.policy=policy.
txt FileServer
FileServer: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1097" "connect
,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"
 "127.0.0.1:1097" "connect,resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at FileServer.main(FileServer.java:11)
```

Line 11 is Naming.rebind().

Here:

```
FileInterface fi = new FileImpl("FileServer");
     Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1:1097/FileServer", fi);
```

I have tried changing the address to localhost, but the same error occurs.

**SOLUTION**

Point to the specific java policy file, either in JRE folder or a specific policy file.

```
java -Djava.security.policy="C:\\FT_RMI\\java.policy" FileServer
```

Comment: You have to allow the socket connect on your security properties under JRE.  You can see this under jre/lib/security/java.policy

Comment: I have tried what you said, i also added a policy file where my code is and pointed to it when i try to run my server. I have tried allowing all permissions as explained in the tutorial. None of which work. Same error everytime. I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Check for which JRE that is being used.  If you have multiple, you might change it at one but executing the program through the other.  Just a thought.  Good luck!

Comment: Finally got there. Thanks for your help. If you put your 1st answer as a propper answer i can accept that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allow the socket connect on your security properties under JRE. You can see this under jre/lib/security/java.policy

Answer (score 0):

You are running your server under a `SecurityManager.` Unless you are using the RMI codebase feature or you have another specific security requirement that dictates its use in the server, just remove it.